# NFS headaches with FreeBSD 4.9

Tags: freebsd, nfs, portmap

Once upon a time, this used to work, and I kept the configuration the same, but... now nothing.

I'm just trying to get an NFS server set up on a FreeBSD 4.9 server. The process should be about as complicated as this:

Add this entry to /etc/exports:

```
/var/home /var/vpopmail/domains -maproot=root XXX.XX.XX.XXX
```

Execute this:

```
portmap
nfsd -u -t -n 4
mountd -r
```

Then this should work, regardless of network and firewall issues:

```
showmount -e localhost
```

But `showmount -e localhost` fails with the following error:

```
RPC: Port mapper failure
showmount: can't do exports rpc
```

And even if I kill off the NFS daemon, and try a `rpcinfo -p localhost`, I get this error:

```
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: rpcinfo: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection reset by peer
```

The portmapper is still running. Why the heck does nothing work as if it isn't?

Edit to add:

FYI: Sockstat gives me this:

```
$ sockstat |egrep "(nfsd|portmap)"
root     nfsd     86310    3 udp4   *:2049                *:*                  
root     nfsd     86310    4 udp4   *:973                 *:*                  
root     portmap  45920    0 tcp4   *:111                 *:*
```

Then, at a later time (say, 5 minutes) it's as if nfsd isn't acting as a server:

```
$ sockstat |egrep "(nfsd|portmap)"
root     portmap  45920    0 tcp4   *:111                 *:*
```

But the nfs daemon is still running:

```
$ ps ax |grep nfsd
86311  ??  I      0:00.00 nfsd: server (nfsd)
86312  ??  I      0:00.00 nfsd: server (nfsd)
86313  ??  I      0:00.00 nfsd: server (nfsd)
86314  ??  I      0:00.00 nfsd: server (nfsd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 4.9 is a bit out of date and not supported anymore, I would consider to upgrade to a supported version of FreeBSD. Anyhow, pls check the following:

```
sockstat | grep portmap
sockstat | grep nfsd
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll replace this mail server with Debian the first chance I get. Until then...

Comment: So go ahead with Debian then. Btw. I would also check the firewall and the rc.conf.

Comment: There is no firewall beyond hosts.allow, which allows all connections from localhost.

Comment: what does the /var/log/messages say?

Comment: Nov  5 09:01:44 pop nfsd:[49627]: can't register with udp portmap
    Nov  5 09:04:04 pop mountd[50063]: can't register mount

Comment: there you go, i guess this is the issue